# jQuery templates pulling in JSON feed from Twitter

Tags: jquery, templates, twitter

Im trying to get a Twitter feed , either using the [search API](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from%3aladygaga) or just using [A standard JSON call](http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/ladygaga.json?count=10&callback=?) Using the code below I just get a blank page. I have included all the correct jQuery elements and have tested it with the [Flikr API](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=border%20collie&format=json&jsoncallback=?) (and have changed the relevant template parts)

```
  <script>
        $().ready(function() {

            $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
                $("body").attribute({message: ""});
            });

            $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/ladygaga.json?count=10&callback=?', function(data) {

                $.template("imageTmpl", $("#imagesTmpl"));
                $.tmpl("imageTmpl", data, {

                }).appendTo("#img_list");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <article id="img_list">
        <script id="imagesTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            {{each items}}
                {{if $index <= 4}}
        ${$text}

                {{/if}}
            {{/each}}
        </script>
    </article>
</body>
```

and ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. change your template syntax, you don't need each in this situation, the template engine displays every array key it gets by default
2. keep an eye on your brackets - right syntax is always ${text}.

[find working demo here ...](http://jsfiddle.net/c5H3A/2/)

so here's the html:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <article id="img_list">
        <ul>
        <script id="imagesTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
            <li>${text}<br/><br/></li>
        </script>
    </ul>
    </article>
</body>
```

and here is a slightyl modified js:

```
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/ladygaga.json?count=10&callback=?', function(data) {
    $.template("imageTmpl", $("#imagesTmpl"));
    $.tmpl("imageTmpl", data).appendTo("#img_list");
});
```

Comment: Thanks , that works great! extra points for showing me jsfiddle. very useful. Do you think this can be done using the API ? Ive tried :       $.ajax({ url: 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:ladygaga&callback=?', data: data, success: callback}); but this is blank. I cannot work out why ,it almost seems like its not even attempting a request...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from:ladygaga&since_id=52754280024784896&callback=?', function(data) {
    $.template("imageTmpl", $("#imagesTmpl"));
    $.tmpl("imageTmpl", data.results).appendTo("#img_list");
   });
  });
 </script>
</head>

<body>

<article id="img_list">
 <script id="imagesTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <li>${text}<br/><br/></li>
 </script>
</article>